# Understanding virtual machines in docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, docker-machine

At begin, I would like to highlight that I have some experience with docker containers, I am aware of the fact that containers is not virtual machine and that the difference is huge, I know also that docker containers are simply processes enclosed in namepsaces and cgroups.

However, yesterday I have read about something like:
`docker-machine create --driver virtualbox containerhost`

I was able to understand that it is strictly connected to `docker swarm` stack, however I would like to understand how does  it work in details. To make this issue more clear I will ask specific questions:

1. Can we create virtual machine using tool `docker-machine` ? If yes, what system will be chosen ? Can we ssh to this machine ?
2. Despite the fact I have never used `docker-machine` after typing `docker-machine ls`  I can see one machine. What is it ?

Answer (score 0):

You *can* think of a docker ?instance? (running container) as a super-light-weight virtual machine.  But since the base image is so clearly defined, the VM host (in your case, VirtualBox) knows how to pass almost all activity directly (or almost directly) on to the host OS.

Under the covers, the running container is a *nix system.  You can SSH to it once you've got it configured to host ssh connections.

This link should answer your questions about docker-machine: https://docs.docker.com/machine/overview/#what-is-docker-machine

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:

1. Yes, it creates a virtual machine supporting several providers. It is a normal virtual machine that you can access via ssh
2. Its purpose is to expose docker daemon, so it can be managed remotely.

Long answer:

[docker-machine](https://docs.docker.com/machine/overview/) is a way of managing remote docker daemons.
Those daemons are, as usual, installed on a server (and bound to a TCP port). (this answer 2).

Common usages include:

- Install and run Docker on Mac or Windows
- Provision and manage multiple remote Docker hosts
- Provision Swarm clusters

It provides [drivers](https://docs.docker.com/machine/drivers/) that allows you to create virtual machine in several providers: Oracle Virtualbox, AWS, Azure, Digital Ocean...